# IsAvailable always false with Kinect Studio on IsAvailableChanged

Tags: wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

Environ: Kinect 2.0 SDK, Kinect Studio, Windows 10, WPF

e.IsAvailailable is always returning false when I'm driving my programming via the Kinect Studio (  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinectsensor.isavailable.aspx ).  I would think it would return true if it were receiving data.  Note the BodyReader frames are arriving even though the sensor started unavailable and never tripped the IsAvailableChanged handler.  Note the BodyBasics-WPF SDK 2.0 sample behaves the same way.

A number of code samples stop if they get e.IsAvailable=false.  Probably a bad move if you are using Kinect Studio and playback.

Bug? Feature? Lack of documentation?

Kinect against Kinect Studio - IsAvailable = false

[image]

Kinect against Physical Kinect - IsAvailable = true

[image]

Code and XAML below...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private KinectSensor m_kinectSensor = null;
    private BodyFrameReader m_bodyReader;
    private Body[] m_bodies = null;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.m_kinectSensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();
        this.m_kinectSensor.IsAvailableChanged += KinectSensor_IsAvailableChanged;
        this.m_kinectSensor.Open();

        // hook the body stuff
        this.m_bodyReader = m_kinectSensor.BodyFrameSource.OpenReader();
        this.m_bodyReader.FrameArrived += BodyReader_FrameArrived;

        InitializeComponent();
        Msg("MainWindow c'tor completed");
    }

    private void BodyReader_FrameArrived(object sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Msg(String.Format("BodyReader_FrameArrived: {0}" , e.FrameReference.RelativeTime.ToString()));
    }

    private void KinectSensor_IsAvailableChanged(object sender, IsAvailableChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "KinectSensor_IsAvailableChanged: e.IsAvailable=" + e.IsAvailable.ToString() );
        TextBlock_StatusBar.Text = "KINECT SENSOR STATUS: " + e.IsAvailable.ToString();
    }

    private void Msg ( string s )
    {
        if (s.Length <= 0) s = "ready";
        TextBlock_Msg.Text = s;
    }
}
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="FaceNSkinWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FaceNSkinWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="600" Width="800" 
    >
<Grid Margin="10,10,10,10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="ButtonOne" Width="150" Height="30" Margin="10"/>
        <Button Content="ButtonOne" Width="150" Height="30" Margin="10"/>
        <Button Content="ButtonOne" Width="150" Height="30" Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Viewbox>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock_StatusBar" Height="20" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" Text="KINECT SENSOR STATUS: unknown"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock_Msg" Height="20" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="Bold" Text="ready"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I can give your code a proper test tomorrow but in the mean time you've set your project platform target to x64, correct?

Comment: Yep, x64. Code works, its just that even is never raised.  If you'd like I can post it up somewhere for you in "completeness" and you can look at it.  Let me know.....

Comment: code sample is available at https://github.com/jhealy/kinect2 .  enjoy...

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was busy yesterday struggling with a few of my own Kinect installations. :) Your project runs fine on my machine. IsAvailable is true, the callback gets called properly (first with false then again with true) and the skeleton appears when I'm in the view frustum. I'd start looking into your USB hardware connection and your SDK version, my own Kinect Studio is at v 2.0.1410.19000.

Comment: Also on Win10 btw and ran this particular demo with VS Express 2012.

Comment: Does IsAvailable return TRUE when running against a Kinect Studio playback when the Kinect is NOT connected to the machine?

The issue is not with IsAvailable with a physical Kinect, but rather with a Kinect Studio playback.  

Had someone inside msft confirm the behavior independently.  I will update the original post with some pics.

All drivers are the latest.

Comment: Sorry Joe, I obviously didn't read your question correctly first time round. No, on my machine IsAvailable always returns false when the Kinect is not physically connected, including when I'm playing back data through Kinect Studio. I think you're right, that does look like an oversight on their part.

Comment: thanks for checking it out mark